# Synology cannot find nas after reinstall windows 8

Tags: windows-8.1, nas, synology

My NAS was working fine, I could logon to the web interface through the Synology Assistant and map the drive. But after reinstalling Windows 8 and updating it to 8.1 the Synology Assistant cannot find my NAS. Im able to find the NAS with [web nas finder](http://find.synology.com/) so it's not a network or configuration issue.

I've tried disabling my virusscanner (network protection) and firewall, but they din't cause problems before and it does not help now.

Also one time I got really far connecting. It was after the [web nas finder](http://find.synology.com/) found my NAS. I tried to map the NAS, but it kept asking for username password even though it never says they are wrong. I tried entering the username/password I need to logon to the NAS itself like 5-6 times. I tried restarting the NAS.

Windows 8.1 Pro, all updates
Dell Lattitude E6530
Classic shell and [remove metro apps](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-remove-all-bundled-modern-apps-from-your-user-account-in-windows-8/) to banish the metro interface.

Comment: This may sound odd.. but try restarting the NAS? (I had the same brand NAS and when strange things like that happened, it usually fixed after a restart)

Comment: @Darius, Yes I tried that.

Comment: Try creating a new acc and see if you can login using the new acc?

Comment: Can't believe it works now, don't know if it's because of the extra account, but I did nothing else.

Comment: The problem seems to be avast network protection was blocking it.